# How to make JTextField lose its focus?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

Exacly as stated in the subject how to make JTextField lose its focus?

Something like:

`jtf.setFocus(false)`

Comment: set the focus on the desired component, then the `JTextField` in question automatically lose the focus.

Comment: See also `setFocusable(false)` & especially `setEnabled(false)`.  If you truly do not want to allow the user to enter or copy data in a field, it is a *very* effective way to ensure it is not focused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply transfer focus to another component:

```
myOtherComponent.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to transfer the focus use this:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().clearFocusOwner();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call `requestFocus()` method from another control

Comment: The proper method to use is requestFocusInWindow().

Answer (score 0):

One can also focus on a panel so that it would look like no components were focused

```
jpanel1.requestFocusInWindow();
```